# Django doesn't submit my form if I using individual fields

Tags: python, django, forms, submit

I need to render my Django form fields individually because of design purposes. It looks good but if I hit submit It doesn't do anything just a short blink. If I render the whole `{{ form }}` it works well. I don't have any ideas about what am I doing wrong. Could you guys please help me?

**html**

```
<form method = "POST">
    <div class="container w-75 bg-light rounded-3 pt-3">
        <div class="form-group">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% comment %} {{ form }} {% endcomment %}

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 border-right border-primary p-3">
            <h6 class="text-primary">1. text.</h6>
            {{ form.att_v001 }}<br>
            </div>
        
            <div class="col-4  border-primary  pt-3 pl-4">
            <h6 class="text-primary">2.text.</h6>
            {{ form.att_v002 }}<br>
            </div>
       

            <div class="col-4 border-left border-primary pt-3 pl-4">
            <h6 class="text-primary">3. text.</h6>
            {{ form.att_v003 }}<br>
            </div>

            <div class="col-4 border-left border-primary pt-3 pl-4">
            <h6 class="text-primary">4. text.</h6>
            {{ form.att_v004 }}<br>
            </div>

            <div class="col-4 border-left border-primary pt-3 pl-4">
            <h6 class="text-primary">5. text.</h6>
            {{ form.att_v005 }}<br>
            </div>

            <div class="col-4 border-left border-primary pt-3 pl-4">
            <h6 class="text-primary">6. text.</h6>
            {{ form.att_v006 }}<br>
            </div>

        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Mentés</button>
```

**models.py**

```
class Attitud(models.Model):

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user_name)

class question(models.IntegerChoices):
    Nem_jellemző = 0
    Néha_jellemző = 1
    Nagyon_jellemző = 2

user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
att_v001 = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=False, choices=question.choices)
att_v002 = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=False, choices=question.choices)
att_v003 = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=False, choices=question.choices)
att_v004 = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=False, choices=question.choices)
att_v005 = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=False, choices=question.choices)
att_v006 = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=False, choices=question.choices)
```

**forms.py**

```
class AttitudForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Attitud
    fields = '__all__'

    widgets = {
        'att_v001': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'custom-radio-list'}),
        'att_v002': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'custom-radio-list'}),
        'att_v003': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'custom-radio-list'}),
        'att_v004': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'custom-radio-list'}),
        'att_v005': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'custom-radio-list'}),
        'att_v006': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'custom-radio-list'}),
    }
```

**views.py**

```
def stressz_item(request):
form = AttitudForm(request.POST or None)

if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    form.user_name = request.user
    
    return redirect('/stressz/main.html')
return render(request, 'stressz/attitud-form.html', {'form':form})

class AttitudCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Attitud
    form_class = AttitudForm
    template_name = 'stressz/attitud-form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user_name = self.request.user

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the action attribute from your html form.

So,

1. add the action attribute, eg:

   action="{% url 'application_name: url_path_name' %}"
2. add it to your URLConf eg:

   path('url_path/', views.view_name, name='url_path_name'),

Note that you link the views in the URLConf file (usually and by default urls.py) to the form rendered in the template.